# What does OWASP mean by max incidence and average incidence rate?

Tags: injection, owasp-top-ten

Can someone please explain what is meant by the following analysis provided in the overview section of the [OWASP Top 10 A03:2021 – Injection page](https://owasp.org/Top10/A03_2021-Injection/):

> Injection slides down to the third position. 94% of the applications
> were tested for some form of injection with a max incidence rate of
> 19%, an average incidence rate of 3%, and 274k occurrences. Notable
> Common Weakness Enumerations (CWEs) included are CWE-79: Cross-site
> Scripting, CWE-89: SQL Injection, and CWE-73: External Control of File
> Name or Path.

I can see this data is used as a measure of some kind of prevalence of a particular category of vulnerability/weakness and indeed was used to move Injection from A01 in the 2017 OWASP Top 10 to A03 in the 2021 version. [The introduction page](https://owasp.org/Top10/A00_2021_Introduction/) adds more context,

> 33 CWEs mapped into this category have the second most occurrences in applications with 274k occurrences. Cross-site Scripting is now
> part of this category in this edition.

but I'm struggling to understand what precisely the numbers are referencing.

What exactly does the 19% refer to? The greatest number of CWE's found when testing for injection on a single instance of one of the applications tested?  Additionally, what exactly is meant by an *'occurrence'* and how is this different to an *'incidence'*?

[The methodology explains these terms as follows;](https://owasp.org/Top10/A00_2021_Introduction/#methodology)

> Incidence Rate: Incidence rate is the percentage of applications
> vulnerable to that CWE from the population tested by that org for that
> year.

> Total Occurrences: Total number of applications found to have the CWEs
> mapped to a category.

This might just be me being silly (very, VERY possible), but can someone please explain this to me in plain English please?

Comment: Not a silly question at all. Data without quoting the sources and the methodologies are, at best, useless. At worst a fraud. Hope to see OWASP add a detailed description of how they produce such numbers or a link to it if it exists already.

Comment: Occurrence vs Incidence looks simply to be a sum vs a percentage. As per the definition.

Comment: I think the only confusion for me is simply what is meant, exactly, by "Max Incident Rate". Max of what domain? It's part of their core stats: https://www.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/owasp-top-10.pdf and https://owasp.org/Top10/A11_2021-Next_Steps/

Comment: The main link explains the data and the methodology. That's not the problem here. The problem is just the definition of the one term. Everything else is clearly explained.